# Find a constant if you know the limit

Tags: limits

$$ \lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\ln\left(\frac{2+x\:}{x}\right)A\cdot x\right)\:=\:3$$

**How can I find A ?**

I tried to use the limits rules but I get a different answer every time.

**One of my solutions:**
$$ \lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\ln\left(\frac{2+x}x\right)A\cdot x\right)=3$$
$$ \lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\ln\left(\frac2x+1\right)A\cdot x\right)=3$$
$$ \lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\underbrace{\frac{\ln\left(\frac2x+1\right)}{\frac2x}}_{\to1}A\cdot2\right)=3$$
$$1\cdot2A=3\implies A=\frac32.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you've tried more than once, please show your attempts.

Comment: Next time please [type your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) (I did it for you).

Answer (score 0):

Recall that when $t\to0$, the following limit holds:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log (1+t)}{t}=1 $$
Now, as $x\to +\infty$, consider $t=2/x$:
$$3=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\log\left(\frac{2+x}{x} \right)Ax=2A\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac2x \right)}{2/x}=2A$$
Hence $A=3/2$.

Comment: Essentially the same as the OP's prior solution 1 hour before.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's formula,
$$Ax\log\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)=Ax\left(\frac{2}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)=2A+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
as $x\to\infty$. Consequently, $$A\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)=2A=3\Rightarrow A=3/2.$$

Comment: Essentially the same as the OP's prior solution 2 hours before and the other previous answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval. The OP was concerned that they were getting different answers every time. I confirm $A=3/2$ with mine. Quite nice of you to go out of your way and label our answers as "useless".

Comment: Confirmation was useful but a short comment would have been sufficient for that. What I found useless was repeating the OP's proof.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is ok.

Note that you can even prove the existence of $A,$ instead of assuming it a priori: simply prove (along the same lines) that
$$\lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\ln\left(\frac{2+x\:}{x}\right)\cdot x\right)=2.$$